# How to build kernel loadable module on raspberry pi as /lib/modules/4.1.18+/build is not present

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian, kernel-module

I am trying to build kernel loadable module on raspberry pi using **$ make** command but it is showing following error.

**/lib/modules/4.1.18+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.**

So how can I build my kernel loadable module on raspberry pi?

Comment: I have seen such error long time ago. I think you  need to create a link to your linux source directory.

Comment: Install Linux kernel headers first.